# How can I make this code stop after the first input

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter your salary per hour: ");
        int salary = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter number of hours: ");
        int hours = input.nextInt();
        
        int sum = salary * hours;
        if (hours == 0) {
            System.out.println("Stop!");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Total salary " + sum);
    }
}}
```

I want to be able to enter numbers until I press 0, and then I want the program to stop. It stops after two zeros, but how can I make it stop after pressing only one zero? I have tried this while-if loop and different do-while loops, I just can't make it work.

Comment: by putting an `if` after the salary read and checking if the salary is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exit whenever you type `0`, then you have to check every value after its input.
There is the code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("What's your salary per hour? ");
        int salary = scanner.nextInt();
        if (salary == 0)
            exit();

        System.out.print("How many hours did you worked today? ");
        int hours = scanner.nextInt();
        if (hours == 0)
            exit();

        int sum = salary * hours;
        System.out.println("Your total salary is " + sum);
    }
}

private static void exit() {
    System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Please write a comment if that doesn't match your expectation

Answer (score 1):

Your code does exactly what you tell it to do.

You tell it to:

- first ask for TWO numbers
- to then compare the first number, and stop on 0

So, the solution is:

- ask for one number
- compare the number, stop on 0
- ask for the second number